# How can I avoid using set_index = False?

Tags: python

For school I'm making a bar chart with the following code which needs me to do this: `df.groupby("Month", as_index=False).mean()`, however we haven't learned about set_index=False yet, is there any way I can avoid this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mean as_index? since that’s what you’re using here. also is learning about it from the documentation not a valid reason to use a method?

Comment: Why would you remove something just because your teacher hasn't mentioned it? That's a good intro to programming; if you're not looking up 10s of things you're unfamiliar with _each day_ while you're learning, you're not going to progress.

Comment: just use it, that's the point of programming. learning new things constantly

Comment: Here is the documentation page for [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). This will tell you what is does. But without knowing anything about your dataset we can't _really_ suggest alternatives. You haven't even mentioned what module(s) you're using for plotting!